# tfs Source Control Explorer>File>Advanced>unlock disabled

Tags: command-line, visual-studio-2012, team-foundation-server

I'm sure I have given all the rights to my account and I'm the Project & Build Administrator for my project.

All our work machines have recently been formatted, and VS2012 has been installed afresh. We did the mapping to our respective work-spaces. Everything works fine, except for one developer who did not check-in before his machine was formatted, so that file has remained checked-out and locked in his workspace. Even administrators are not allowed to unlock that file.

In Visual-Studio 2012 & Team Foundation Server 2012: 
Source Control Explorer>File>Advances>unlock option is 
disabled. See Image below :
[image]

Please help. I have tried many commands from the Visual Studio command prompt  which didn't seem to work.

Here are some commands that I've tried:

```
tf lock /lock:none /workspace:uto27; uto\pavitar  $/socialmediaweb

tf lock /lock:none /server:http://192.168.0.116:8080/tfs/bv_collection /workspace:uto27;uto\pavitar $/SocialMedia/SocialMediaWeb/SocialMediaWeb/ChatterAdvanced2.aspx.cs /recursive

tf undo /server:http://192.168.0.116:8080/tfs/bv_collection /workspace:uto27;uto\pavitar $/SocialMedia/SocialMediaWeb/SocialMediaWeb/ChatterAdvanced2.aspx.cs /recursive
```

Comment: Any findings? I'm stumped with this as well

Comment: refer to one of my other SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545424/tfs-2012-the-working-folder-is-already-in-use-after-hard-disk-format . Though this may not directly solve the problem, but will give you a direction

Answer (score 0):

try this in Visual studio command prompt i hope it will work...

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0>tf undo
     {tfsfilepath} /Workspace:{tfsusername}

     Undo your changes to {Filepath} (Yes/No) yes
```